# Wallpaper is not correct displayed after migrating tu Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: desktop-background

migration to 20.04 was for me a big problem. Migration was stopped and it takes 2 days to solve all the broken and hold packages. Now is Ubuntu 20.04 working. But the  desktop wallpaper will not work. I ask the friend Google with no results.

Here is what I found out that I can change the the wallpaper using Settings an Tweak. The only change on the desktop is that I see a small (8mm) on the right side of the desktop is changing as wallpaper. See attached screen shot. This small area changes as I changed the wallpaper. Regardless which option I use (Zoom, ...) it shows only this small wallpaper and the remaining desktop is black. Except when I select "None", then is there complete black desktop.
Any ideas where to look whats wrong?

Thanks in advance Rainer
[image: Screen shot of the desktop with a small, partional wallpaper]

Comment: Either: 1) disable all Gnome-Shell extensions, and themes, and retry, 2) backup your data and do a clean install of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for Your comment. This help me to find the reason for the black desktop. The gnome extension "Workspace Indicator" is responsible for the black desktop. Deactivating them shows my selected wallpaper.

I will report the error to the Workspace Indicator development.

Thanks again and regards Rainer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, problem reoccurs. I then uninstall all gnome shell extension. Problem is still there. It shows now a little bit different: The normal desktop is black. If I press the Super key I will see the wallpaper. Great. See the screen shots.
[image: Screen shot of black desktop]

[![Screen shot after pressing Super key][2]][2]

Any more hints?

Thanks and regards Rainer
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDiwj.png